# add Authentication to new session

Tags: java, session, url, authentication, cas

i have a mvc project with cas. in a controller class A, i use

```
URL url = new URL("...");
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
```

so a new session will be created and should be handled by another controller B. Although i have a succsesful login, the new session will be blocked by cas and the controller B dosent respond.

has someone ideas? how can i add authentication to this new session within controller A.

i have tried with

```
HttpURLConnection connection = ( HttpURLConnection ) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization",(new StringBuilder("Basic "))      .append((new BASE64Encoder()).encode((new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(proxyUser)))
.append(":").append(proxyPassword).toString().getBytes())).toString());
```

or with

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", ...)
```

and dosent work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just append the password. The header requires a base64 encoded string, in the form "username:password".  Currently you are converting a string to a byte array and then back to a string.